# Conteo d registros y verificar mayor hora de registros por Mes SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Actualmente tengo este Script

```
SELECT 
 T.MONTO
,T.MES 
,T.HORA

FROM TABLA T

WHERE T.MES = 'Junio'
```

Y obtengo el siguiente resultado (es una muestra pequeña con datos aleatorios)

```
MontoPagado     Mes        Hora
3302.51        Junio      1:00PM
4327.16        Junio      1:15PM
4648.25        Junio      1:20PM
136.46         Junio      1:20PM
460.6          Junio      1:20PM
590.79         Junio      5:00PM
231.18         Junio      1:00PM
354.37         Junio      9:00PM
446.81         Junio      8:00PM
465.96         Junio      1:00PM
83.36          Junio      7:00PM
67.43          Junio      1:00PM
1941.97        Junio      1:00PM
1895.91        Junio      1:00PM
300.24         Junio      1:00PM
1819.28        Junio      6:20PM
3168.39        Junio      1:00PM
1521.55        Junio      1:00PM
665.1          Junio      1:00PM
2875.24        Junio      1:00PM
1484.67        Junio      1:00PM
160.17         Junio      1:00PM
61.22          Junio      1:00PM
1069.27        Junio      1:00PM
684.32         Junio      1:00PM
1942.57        Junio      8:05PM
160.17         Junio      8:20PM
2289.05        Junio      8:00PM
991.42         Junio      8:00PM
2065.1         Junio      4:05PM
108.68         Junio      3:07PM
952.2          Junio      1:00PM
594.53         Junio      1:00PM
2163.7         Junio      1:09PM
891            Junio      1:09PM
620.36         Junio      3:00PM
555.55         Junio      3:21PM
91.39          Junio      3:00PM
259.65         Junio      3:00PM
```

lo que quiero hacer, es saber la hora en la que mas registros tiene la tabla, por ejemplo hay registros que fueron realizados a la 1 de la tarde (no importa los minutos)
,como lo estoy filtrando por mes, el resultado que espero es este:

```
MES       [Hora Con Mayor Transaccion]     [Cantidad de Transacciones]
Junio             1 PM                                 24
```

Como ven como lo filtre por mes, quiero que me muestre que en ese mes en la hora 1 pm es donde se realizo la mayor cantidad de registros y muestro el total que es 24

Como puedo realizar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas realizar básicamente estas 5 operaciones para obtener el resultado que buscas:

- Quedarte solamente con la información de hora, sin minutos, del campo hora actual. Esto lo puedes lograr con la función [`datepart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql), pasándole la *parte* `hour` como parámetro. Esto te devolverá un número entero entre 0 y 23.

  ```
    datepart(hour, T.Hora)
  ```
- Agrupar por esta *hora* y utilizar la función de agregación [`count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql) para saber cuántos registros *pertenecen* a dicha hora, por ejemplo:

  ```
    select T.Mes, datepart(hour, T.Hora), count(1)
      from Tabla T
     where T.Mes = 'Junio'
     group by t.Mes, datepart(hour, T.Hora)
  ```
- Ordenar de mayor a menor por el resultado de la función `count()`. Si hay dos horas que tienen la misma *cuenta*, el orden entre estas estaría indefinido, por lo que yo recomiendo agregar otro campo, por ejemplo la hora misma, para que la instrucción sea precisa y obtengamos siempre el mismo resultado, por ejemplo:

  ```
    order by count(1) desc, datepart(hour, T.Hora)
  ```
- Luego, quedarte solo con la primera fila de ese resultado, que será la primera de la ordenación, y por tanto la primera *hora* que tenga más registros. Esto lo puedes lograr utilizando la cláusula [`top`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql):

  ```
    select top 1....
  ```
- Finalmente, convertir el resultado de nuevo en un campo de tipo *time*. Para ello, puedes

  - Convertir el número devuelto por `datepart()` en un varchar utilizando la función `cast()`, por ejemplo:

    ```
    cast(10 as varchar(10))
    ```
  - Concatenarle `':00'`, para tener cadenas tipo `7:00` o `21:00`

    ```
    cast(7 as varchar(10)) + ':00'
    ```
  - Pasarle esta cadena a la función `cast`, solicitando el tipo de dato `time` como resultado:

    ```
    cast('7:00' as time)
    ```

El código dice más que mil palabras, la consulta que integra todo lo dicho, sería como esta:

```
select top 1   
         T.Mes
       , cast(cast(datepart(hour, T.Hora) as varchar(10)) + ':00' as time) [Hora con mayor transaccion]
       , count(1) [Cantidad de Transacciones]
  from Tabla T
 where Mes = 'Junio'
 group by T.Mes, datepart(hour, T.Hora)
 order by count(1) desc, datepart(hour, T.Hora)
```

Devuelve:

```
Mes   Hora con mayor transaccion Cantidad de Transacciones
----- -------------------------- -------------------------
Junio 13:00:00.0000000           24

(1 row affected)
```

**Advertencia:** Todo lo dicho asume que el tipo de dato del campo `Hora` es `Time`. En caso de no ser así, te tocará hacer los ajustes necesarios para trabajar con el tipo de dato que tengas en tu base de datos real.